# How to delete a folder in windows with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, directory, windows-10

I have a folder in windows that's name is `RESIDENCES INC.`. The problem is this is actually an invalid foldername because of the period in it. If I try to delete it, it says

`Could not find this item. This is no longer located in <path to folder>. Verify the item's location and try again.`

How can I remove it with code?

Comment: Can you show us how you're attempting to delete it?

Answer (score 2):

That's weird, might be a Windows thing? It worked fine for me:

```
PS /home/Documents/test> mkdir "RESIDENCES INC."

PS /home/Documents/test> gi './RESIDENCES INC./'


    Directory: /home/Documents/test

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           3/18/2021 12:04 AM                RESIDENCES INC.

PS /home/Documents/test> (gi './RESIDENCES INC./').FullName
/home/Documents/test/RESIDENCES INC./

PS /home/Documents/test> Remove-Item (gi './RESIDENCES INC./').FullName -Force

PS /home/Documents/test> (gi './RESIDENCES INC./').FullName                   

Get-Item: Cannot find path '/home/Documents/test/RESIDENCES INC./' because it does not exist.
PS /home/Documents/test>
```

Can you paste the command you're using to delete the folder?

Comment: is interesting way to do, but does not work for me